# create interface or public methods for android service

Tags: android, android-service

If i have a service that i have created and started running in android.. and the class for that service has a public method that takes a String paramater..  Is there a way to call that public method from an adroid activity?  I started that service like so:

```
Intent backOverlayService = new Intent(TiApplication.getAppCurrentActivity(), 
ForegroundService.class); 
mContext.startService(backOverlayService);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to bind your service instead of starting it.

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

                mService = ((MyService.ServiceBinder) service).getService();


    }


public MyService getService() {
        return mService;
}
```

Comment: but if i bind it doesn't that mean if my activity dies it dies?

Comment: i created the service connection according to android documentation, but the [bindService] method is not showing up as a valid method.. i have imported android.content.Context but still nadda